# Differentiate two ActiveRecord association instances, one that was eager loaded and one that was not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let’s say I have these ActiveRecord models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emotions
end

class Emotion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And I have this code:

```
user1 = User.where(id: 1).includes(:emotions).first
user2 = User.where(id: 1).first
```

Is there a way to differentiate `user1.emotions` and `user2.emotions`? Is there a method I can call on them to know if the relation has been eager loaded or is still waiting to be queried from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have just looked into ActiveRecord’s [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e4ec9ce78d879fc20bae0c5c7886a3bdbfab096c/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb#L55-L58).

```
user1.emotions.loaded? # => true
user2.emotions.loaded? # => false
```

`#loaded?` is what I was looking for.